# Help with datasheet for isolated DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Currently writing a bachelors thesis of a power distribution system.

Have been checking websites like mouser.com for DC-DC converters to test before making my final decision which kind I am going to choose. I'm having a slight problem understanding the information provided on the website and/or datasheet.

How can I figure out what kind of isolated converter I'm currently looking at?

And, for the DPA423-426 from mouser.com. What does it mean the converter is both forward and flyback?

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Power-Integrations/DPA423PN?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu6TJb8E8Cjr3sTIccEzm0g

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: That's not a converter, just the integratd PWM IC+FET and you need to provide everything else around it, transformer, capacitors and so on before it becomes a converter. You can connect it in either flyback or forward configuration.

Comment: winny is correct. Figure 1 in the datasheet diagrams how you would connect the chip for forward mode, with the DPA42X itself marked as Control. It should not be listed as a DC-DC, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! However an DC-DC such as the CME0505DC, https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/CME0505DC?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvGsmoEFRKS8ON39RzVWk5jlt%252bTYU1fcXe6aEwJ3AX32w%3d%3d is there any way to see easily what kind it is?

Comment: Application note on converter topologies: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/2a/8c/7f/9e/70/6b/43/62/CD00003910.pdf/files/CD00003910.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003910.pdf